# Get a collection of single objects among groups in LINQ or Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a collection of categories, each of the categories contains a collection of models.

I want to get a collection of models from these instances.

```
var topModels = Model.Categories.Select(c => c.TopModels ?? Enumerable.Empty<MyModel>());
```

If I wrote like the above, it returns a collection of collections (`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyModel>>`).
But I need something like `IEnumerable<MyModel>`.

I just don't know how to get them right in a simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Select` on `IEnumerable<T>` will return `IEnumerable<T>`. This is applied to your case too.

Since `c` (that is, the `T`) contains `IEnumerable<MyModel>` (which is in a variable called `TopModels`), your `Select` return `IEnumerable<T>` which is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyModel>>`

Look at the `SelectMany` instead. It is used to "flatten" your `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` to `IEnumerable<T>`. That is, using `SelectMany` on `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` will return `IEnumerable<T>`

Something like:

```
var topModelsEnumerable = Model.Categories.SelectMany(c => c.TopModels != null);
```

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var topModels = Model.Categories.SelectMany(c => c.TopModels);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the SelectMany method instead Select, also know as FlatMap

```
var topModels = Model.Categories.SelectMany(c => c.TopModels);
```

#### SelectMany

> Projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>` and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx